# Scala Akka Typed - pipeToSelf

Tags: scala, akka

I'm trying to use the new Akka Actor API. I want to pipe the result of a `Future` to actor that invoked it. To do this, I'm using `pipeToSelf`. However, I'm getting this error:

*not enough arguments for method pipeToSelf: (future: java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage[Value], applyToResult: akka.japi.function.Function2[Value,Throwable,EmailActor.Command])Unit.*

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue? It's resulting from this code snippet.

```
val emailResult: Future[Unit] = mailer(email)

context.pipeToSelf(emailResult) {
  case Success(_) =>
    EmailSuccess(replyTo)
  case Failure(e) =>
    SendFailed(replyTo)
}
```

Side Notes:

- The messages extend `Command`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely referencing `akka.actor.typed.javadsl.ActorContext` and not `akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.ActorContext` as you expect. Check your imports